# PHP find patern in php

Tags: php

I have a string like

```
$str="with a little love this home can be hud case # 351-377554. property sold as-is. information from sources deemed reliable but not guaranteed. buyer to verify all information. streamline k eligible.";
```

here i need to get `# 351-377554`

Comment: Go ahead, do it then.

Comment: This is not a code you site for you service!!!!!

Comment: Sorry @RiggsFolly :/ :P

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression.

```
<?php

$str="with a little love this home can be hud case # 351-377554. property sold as-is. information from sources deemed reliable but not guaranteed. buyer to verify all information. streamline k eligible.";

preg_match("/# [0-9]{3}-[0-9]+/", $str, $matches);

print_r( $matches );
```

- [Live preview](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2aa89324deb9c946dfd325739970f949ae013a8d)
- [Regular Expression test](http://regexr.com/397cq)

Comment: Your solution does not match "# " as in question was requested.

Comment: Altered solution! Thanks @BerndOtt

Answer (score 0):

İf the number is always in same format (i.e. starts with # and ends with .) then you can use:

```
$exploded1 = explode('#', $str);
$exploded2 = explode('.', $exploded1[1]);
echo $exploded2[0]; //will echo number
```

You can [check explode function here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)